# Prove that $m$ is a measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X,Σ)$ be a measurable space and let a function $m : Σ → [0,+∞)$ satisfy the following
two conditions:

(i) $m(A∪B) = m(A)+m(B)$ whenever $A,B ∈ Σ$ and $A∩B = \emptyset$;

(ii) $m(\bigcup_{i≥1} S_i) = \lim _{i→∞} m(S_i)$ whenever $S_i ∈ Σ$ and $S_I ⊆ S_{i+1}$ for all $i ≥ 1$.

Prove that $m$ is a measure.

---

So I need to prove that $m(\emptyset )=0$ which I am very unsure of because how do we know this from the info given?

Can we do this: $A \cup \emptyset = A$ and $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ so using the first condition, $m(a \cup \emptyset)=m(A)=m(A)+m(\emptyset) \implies m(\emptyset)=0$

Then we have to prove $m(\bigcup_{i\ge 1}S_i)=\sum_{i\ge 1}m(S_i)$ such that these sets are pairwise disjoint. But doesn't this just follow off of the first condition?

But that would be weird because we haven't used the second condition at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in fact take $A = \emptyset$ for the quickest proof: since $m(\emptyset) = m(\emptyset \cup \emptyset) = 2m(\emptyset)$
 and $m(\emptyset)$ is finite you get $m(\emptyset) = 0$.

The countable additivity doesn't follow directly from finite additivity; it requires "continuity" of the limit. If $\{A_k\}$ is a countable family of pairwise disjoint sets you can define $$S_i = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_i.$$  Then $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \cdots$ and $\cup_i S_i = \cup_k A_k$. For any particular index $i$ the finite additivity gives you $$m(S_i) = \sum_{k=1}^i m(A_k)$$ and the limit in the second condition leads to
$$m( \cup_k A_k) = m(\cup_i S_i) = \lim_{i \to \infty} m(S_i) = \lim_{i \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^i m(A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(A_k).$$

Comment: So we have that $S_1=a_1$ and $S_2=A_1 \cup A_2$. So $S_1 \cup S_2 = A_1 \cup (A_1 \cup A_2 )= A_1 \cup A_2$?